# Entity Framework not using connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

My error message states

> The underlying provider failed on Open

and the InnerException states that the database cannot open by the requested login. 
The strange thing is that my connectionString is showing a different login than what's mentioned in the error. Why is the application using an incorrect connectionString than the one that's explicitly defined in my App.Config?

Comment: Could you paste that section of the App.config?

Comment: How many projects are there in your solution?  Which project has the app.config file, and which project has the WPF or web pages?  The connection string should be in the same project as the one that has the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

Few common reasons why:

1) You aren't using that project as your **StartUp** Project

2) You didn't match the name in the config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourContext"... >
</connectionStrings>
```

3) You are hard coding it in the `YourContext.cs`